# Is there a way to transpose the columns in the following dataframe using pandas functions and/or methods?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

| Person | Date1 | Date2 | Date3 | Code1 | Code2 | Amount1-1 | Amount1-2 | Amount1-3 | Amount2-1 | Amount2-2 | Amount2-3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 12/1/21 | 12/2/21 |  | REGULAR | OVERTIME | 8 | 8 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| Mary |  | 12/2/21 | 12/3/21 | REGULAR | OVERTIME | 0 | 8 | 8 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

The first number after each "Amount" (Amount***1***-2) corresponds to the number after the "Code"  columns (Code***1***) and the second number after each "Amount" (Amount1-***2***) corresponds to the number after the "Date" columns (Date***2***).

I want to transpose the dataframe to the following:

| Person | Date | Code | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 12/1/21 | REGULAR | 8 |
| John | 12/1/21 | OVERTIME | 2 |
| John | 12/2/21 | REGULAR | 8 |
| John | 12/2/21 | OVERTIME | 3 |
| Mary | 12/2/21 | REGULAR | 8 |
| Mary | 12/2/21 | OVERTIME | 1 |
| Mary | 12/3/21 | REGULAR | 8 |

I am currently using a nested for loop to manually populate the dataframe I need, but I am hoping that there is a function or module in pandas that will let me achieve what I need in far less time. Currently, with a much larger file size, this transpose takes over 4 hours.

Edit:
The loop I am using is below. I have adapted it for the condensed example above. I am appending each entry to an empty list then creating a new dataframe using the list. In my complete dataframe there are 42 dates, 20 codes, and 840 amount per persons. A person can have all, none, or some of those values populated in each column. I am also checking if each combination of date, code, and amount has no values. If so, I ignore it. I also ignore any data/code combinations that have a zero amount. It's nasty...

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Person' : ['John', 'Mary'], 'Date1' : ['12/1/21', ''],\
                   'Date2' : ['12/2/21', '12/2/21'], 'Date3' : ['', '12/3/21'], 'Code1' : ['REGULAR', 'REGULAR'],\
                   'Code2' : ['OVERTIME', 'OVERTIME'], 'Amount1-1' : [8, 0],\
                   'Amount1-2' : [8, 8], 'Amount1-3' : [0, 8], 'Amount2-1' : [2, 0],\
                   'Amount2-2' : [3, 1], 'Amount2-3' : [0, 0]})
record_list = []
cols = list(df.columns)
cols.insert(0, "ignore") # .itertuples starts index at 1 instead of 0

for row in df.itertuples():
    for i in range(2, 5):
        for j in range (5, 7):
            for k in range(7, 13):
                if cols[i].strip("Date") == cols[k].strip("Amount").split("-")[1] \
                and cols[j].strip("Code") == cols[k].strip("Amount").split("-")[0]:
                    if not row[i].isspace() and not row[j].isspace() \
                    and float(row[k]) != 0:
                        record_list.append([row[1], row[i], row[j], row[k]])
new_columns = ['Person', 'Date', 'Code', 'Amount']
transposed_df = pd.DataFrame(record_list, columns = new_columns)
```

Comment: could you post the loop you are using for time comparisons?

Comment: Try to look on the side of https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: running your code seems to give a different result than desired (the dates on Johns 8 amount lines) - what am I missing here?

Comment: Ah I see.. error in the code.. will post update soon.

Comment: fixed. amounts in df declaration needed to be switched.

Answer (score 0):

one way is to put the needed values into lists and use explode (no idea if this is faster than your method though), here goes:

```
def get_num_lists(df, col_pref='Amount'):
    cols = [c for c in df.columns if 'Amount' in c]
    list_2 = [x[-1] for x in cols]
    list_1 = [x[-3] for x in cols]
    return list_1, list_2

def num_list_to_values(df, col_pref, num_list):
    return [df[col_pref+str(x)].values[0] for x in num_list]    

def explode_special(df):    
    df0 = pd.DataFrame()
    df0['Person'] = df['Person']
    df0['Amount'] = [df[[c for c in df.columns if 'Amount' in c]].values[0]]
    list1, list2 = get_num_lists(df)
    df0['Date'] = [num_list_to_values(df, 'Date', list1)]
    df0['Code'] = [num_list_to_values(df, 'Code', list2)]
    return df0.explode(['Amount', 'Date', 'Code'])
```

then

```
explode_special(df)
```

|  | Person | Amount | Date | Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John | 8 | 12/1/21 | REGULAR |
| 0 | John | 2 | 12/1/21 | OVERTIME |
| 0 | John | 8 | 12/2/21 | REGULAR |
| 0 | John | 3 | 12/2/21 | OVERTIME |

for applying on many rows you can use groupby('Person').apply(explode_special) or itterrows (with some changes to the functions)

Comment: I'll test this out thanks!

Comment: this will need some changes to work with new data, and in any case slower than your method, mainly it gives different results than your loop which seems to be different than the result you posted as well so I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use Pandas methods, which should be faster than a for loop:

```py
# set `person` as index; makes it easy to filter and dice the columns
temp = df.set_index('Person')

# reshape columns, splitting the numbers out
temp.columns = temp.columns.str.split('([a-zA-Z]+)', expand=True).droplevel(0)
#temporary dataframe for date, code, amount
dates = temp.filter(like='Date')
codes = temp.filter(like='Code')
amount = temp.filter(like='Amount')
# put the numbers into a column
dates = dates.stack(level=1).rename_axis(['Person', 'date'])
codes = codes.stack(level=1).rename_axis(['Person', 'code'])
amount.columns = amount.columns.droplevel(0).str.split('-', expand=True)
amount.columns.names = ['code', 'date']
amount = amount.stack(level=['code', 'date']).reset_index(name='Amount')
# join the tables and filter the final dataframe for only rows
# where amount is greater than 0
(codes.merge(amount, left_index = True, right_on = ['Person', 'code'])
      .merge(dates, left_on=['Person', 'date'], right_index=True)
      .loc[lambda df: df.Amount.gt(0), ['Person', 'Date', 'Code', 'Amount']]
)

   Person     Date      Code  Amount
0    John  12/1/21   REGULAR       8
3    John  12/1/21  OVERTIME       2
1    John  12/2/21   REGULAR       8
4    John  12/2/21  OVERTIME       3
7    Mary  12/2/21   REGULAR       8
10   Mary  12/2/21  OVERTIME       1
8    Mary  12/3/21   REGULAR       8
```